# Synchronize multiple reads and writes in a list of thread safe objects

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety

Let's say that I have a thread safe class Container:

```
public class Container {
  private List<MyObject> objects;
  ...
  public synchronized MyObject take(Type t) {...} //takes an object of type t 
  public synchronized  void put(MyObject o) {...} //put an object
}
```

**Important: MyObject has a method getType() that returns a his type**

Somewhere, I have a list of containers (shared amond threads):

```
List<Container> containers;
```

And I have some threads executing something like this:

```
//This piece of code is not synchronized
for(Container c : containers) {
  Type t = getRandomType();
  MyObject o = c.getObject(t); //note that this is synchronized
  if(o != null) { //if I found an object of the desired type
    //do some important stuff
    return;
  }
}
waitingReaders.putMyself(); //wait for the object of the right type
```

I want to loop over every containers to take an object of the right type.

Then I have other threads doing something like this:

```
//This piece of code is not synchronized
Container c = getRandomContainer(); //from containers
Type t = getRandomType();
MyObject o = new MyObject(t); //creates an object of a random type
if(waitingReaders.containSomeoneWaitingForThisType(t)) {
  waitingReaders.givesObjectToHim(o);
  return;
}
else
  c.put(o); //note that this is synchronized
```

**EDITED:** if a reader does not find the desired object of type t, he puts himself waiting for it inside the structure waitingReaders (it does not matter his implementation). If a writer find a reader waiting for the generated object, then he gives it to the waiting reader (instead of putting in the container).

**The problem is that**, writer threads could put an object of type t inside a certain container **after** a reader thread has already analysed that container in the for loop. So the reader would miss that object if it was of the right type t (it would be already too ahead in the loop).

At the same time, I do not want to lock over the for loop because **I also need to keep concurrent reads**.

**How would you handle the described scenario given these constraints?**

Comment: you have to make sure that the threads are guaranteed to see changes made by other threads. you could use synchronization or volatile variables or the locks provided by java.util.concurrent or by using a Collection suitable for concurrent use like CopyOnWriteArrayList ... not doing any synchronization at all while looping over concurrently updated collections might or might not work depending on various parameters  and may lead to unpredictable behaviour of your code.

Comment: Does it make a difference if another thread puts a new object *after* the loop? If not, then accept that the reader might miss objects *in between* the loop. The outcome is the same.

Comment: @André R.: the question states explicitly that `getObject` *is* `synchronized`

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference because I have simplified a bigger problem. If the reader does not find the object he starts to wait for it and the writer gives the object to the reader (instead of putting it in the container) if he was waiting for it. Maybe I should add this.

Comment: I added more details. The point is that the writer has the task of inform the reader.

Comment: @Holger yes, but it also states that accessing the list in the for-each loop is not synchronized ... a thread might not even see a single element although there are elements written to this container by other threads ... putting something into the container also needs some kind of synchronization ... the java memory model states that every thread has it's own copy of the variables and objects used by a thread and that data is only guaranteed to be flushed / refreshed if threads 'synchronize ' on the same 'locks' (not only synchronized blocks, also volatile variables etc.)

Comment: @André R.: the loop iterates over the `List<Container>`, not over a particular `Container`. The looping over a particular `Container` happens inside the `getObject` method which is `synchronized`. If there are concurrent updates to the `List<Container>`, another synchronization would be needed, however, there was no statement that this is the case.

Comment: @Kami: your question looks like an XY problem. Instead of describing your attempted solution, you should focus on your *problem*. I guess, there is already an existing solution in the JRE that works much better.

Comment: @Holger: I think you are right. I was thinking that maybe it is enough to take each container's lock while iterating in the for loop. I mean, I take the lock of the first container, analyse it, then I take the lock of the second container and so on. At the end of the loop I unlock all the containers. I should be able to avoid insertions in the 'past' of the loop, but allow insertions in the 'future' on the loop concurrently. What do you think?

Comment: @Holger ok, i assumed that concurrent updates to the list happen ... but even if that is not the case you still need to have some kind of synchronization on the list ... Kami says 'Somewhere, I have a list of containers (shared amond threads)' ... and "//This piece of code is not synchronized for(Container c : containers)" ... so this sounds like the thread iterating over a list is not neccesarily the same thread that populated the list ... so if you want to be sure to see all the items in the list you need take care of that ...

Comment: @Kami: why do you have all these different containers? *What problem are you trying to solve?*

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a solution where multiple threads may store `MyObject` instances and multiple threads may retrieve `MyObject` instances of a particular type, all non-blocking with the only exception that when no `MyObject` instances of a requested type is available, the retrieving thread may get blocked until a new instance of the requested type is available.

Don’t try to implement a storage solution yourself. Use the existing concurrency tools:

```
final ConcurrentHashMap<Type, BlockingQueue<MyObject>> map=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
/**
 * Get a object of {@code Type}, blocking if necessary
 */
MyObject getObjectOf(Type t) throws InterruptedException {
    return map.computeIfAbsent(t, x->new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()).take();
}
/**
 * Store an object, never blocking.
 */
void putObject(MyObject o) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(o.getType(), x->new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()).add(o);
}
```

This uses Java 8. If you don’t have Java 8, you have to emulate the `computeIfAbsent` operation:

```
final ConcurrentHashMap<Type, BlockingQueue<MyObject>> map=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
/**
 * Get a object of {@code Type}, blocking if necessary
 */
MyObject getObjectOf(Type t) throws InterruptedException {
    return getQueue(t).take();
}
/**
 * Store an object, never blocking.
 */
void putObject(MyObject o) {
    getQueue(o.getType()).add(o);
}
private BlockingQueue<MyObject> getQueue(Type key) {
    BlockingQueue<MyObject> q=map.get(key);
    if(q!=null) return q;
    BlockingQueue<MyObject> newQueue=new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    q=map.putIfAbsent(key, newQueue);
    return q==null? newQueue: q;
}
```

This uses an unbounded `LinkedBlockingQueue` per `Type` so the only situation where a thread gets blocked is when a thread tries to retrieve an item from an empty queue.